# Ошибка при парсинге IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Пишу парсер, выдает ошибку `IndexError: list index out of range на line 20`. Хочу добиться вывода похожий на `[{'title': 'Энергоуголь XXI', 'city': 'Сарань', 'price': '12,24'}]`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://bankchart.kz/spravochniki/indikatory_rynka/electric_tariff/116487'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36 OPR/72.0.3815.487'}

def get_html(url, params = None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS, params = params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='row')

    provider = []
    for item in items:
        provider.append({
            'title' : item.find('div', class_='col col-currency').get_text(strip = True),
            'city' : item.find('div', class_="col col-currency-rate").get_text(strip = True),
            'price' : item.find_all('div', class_='col-currency-rate')[4].find_all('p')[0].text,
        })

    print(provider)
    print(len(provider))

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print("Error")

parse()
```

Comment: Значит в списке нет того количества элементов, к которому идет обращение. А строчку 20 отсчитывай сам

Comment: у вас тут три таблицы, вы ходите все данные вперемешку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код периодически натыкается на заголовки таблиц, не может извлечь данные по индексу и крашиться на этом тут:

```
'price': item.find_all('div', class_='col-currency-rate')[4].find_all('p')[0].text
```

Самое простое, хотя и не самое эффективное, решение - "завернуть" проблемную часть в try/except:

```
for item in items:
    try:
        provider.append({
            'title': item.find('div', class_='col col-currency').get_text(strip=True),
            'city': item.find('div', class_="col col-currency-rate").get_text(strip=True),
            'price': item.find_all('div', class_='col-currency-rate')[4].find_all('p')[0].text,
        })
    except:
        print('header finded')
```

Результат:

```
>>> parse()
header finded
header finded
header finded
[{'title': 'Энергоуголь XXI', 'city': 'Сарань', 'price': '12,24'}, {'title': 'Энергоуголь XXI', 'city': 'Сарань', 'price': '16,30'}, {'title': 'Энергоуголь XXI', 'city': 'Сарань', 'price': '20,37'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '10,15'}, {'title': 'Расчетный сервисный центр', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '15,69'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '13,46'}, {'title': 'Расчетный сервисный центр', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '19,67'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '16,83'}, {'title': 'Расчетный сервисный центр', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '24,57'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '10,19'}, {'title': 'Расчетный сервисный центр', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '15,69'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '13,46'}, {'title': 'Расчетный сервисный центр', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '19,67'}, {'title': 'Расчетный сервисный центр', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '24,57'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '16,83'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '10,15'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '13,46'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '16,83'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '10,19'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '13,46'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '16,83'}, {'title': 'Энергоуголь XXI', 'city': 'Сарань', 'price': '13,58'}, {'title': 'ҚарағандыЖылуСбыт', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '11,22'}, {'title': 'Расчетный сервисный центр', 'city': 'Карагандинская область', 'price': '16,39'}]
24
```